# Print apsrtable output to file?

Tags: r

Somewhat embarrassing question -- I can't believe I'm struggling to figure this out:

How can I print apsrtable's output to a file?  I was expecting this to work:

```
library(apsrtable)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=(1:10)+rnorm(10))
model1 <- lm(y ~ x, data=df)
model2 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data=df)
print(apsrtable(model1, model2), file="models.tex")
```

...but alas, it seems apsrtable does not come with a print.apsrtable function (the way xtable comes with print.xtable).

What's the proper way to automatically create a .tex file from apsrtable output?

Thank you in advance,

Adrian

Comment: `print.xtable` is a nonstandard method if it writes to a file.  Most `print` methods dump to the console.  You might experiment with `write.table(apsrtable([blahblah]),file="models.tex")` but be warned it will not create a TeX -formatted table if that's what you are after. (so far as I know :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFter writing my comment, I actually looked up the manual :D, and found the following:
(from the manual for apsrtable)

Value 
A character vector containing lines of latex code. It can be written out using `writeLines` for inclusion via \input{} in latex documents.

Sounds like what you want, then, is

```
% writeLines(apsrtable([blahblah]),file="models.tex")
```

Or something closely approximating that.

Comment: Thank you!  Just in case anyone else reads this:  writeLines(apsrtable(model1, model2), file("models.tex")) will do the trick.  I do like the way xtable lets you use print() to "print to file," I find it easier to remember than writeLines()!

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would simply be to use `cat()`. The following worked for me:

```
cat(apsrtable(...), file = "model.tex")
```